# unable to view my model objects in django using cbv

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-class-based-views

i am unble to view my model item in django i did everthing right but my model item i not showing
my model

```
class Quote(models.Model):
    todays_Quote = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=False)
    by = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.todays_Quote
```

my views

```
class home(View):
    def get(self, request):
        quote = Quote.objects.all()
        return render(request, 'home.html', {'qoutes':quote})
```

my html for rendering it

```
<section>
       <div class="col-11">
         <div class="text-center">
         {% for Quote in quotes %}
         <h1>{{ Quote.todays_Quote }} hello</h1>
         <p style="float: right;">{{ Quote.by }}</p>
         <p>Todays Date :- <span id="date"></span></p>
         {% endfor %}
        </div>
       </div>
     </section>
```

any idea what wrong in that & yes i did the migration

page source

```
</nav>
     <section>
       <div class="col-11">
         <div class="text-center">
         
        </div>
       </div>
     </section>
```

Comment: what does `print(quote)` in your view show?

Comment: it does show the quote <QuerySet [<Quote: Honesty is the first chapter in the book of wisdom.>]>

Comment: no idea what wrong here

Comment: @yedpodtrzitko i also tried function base views but didn't happen anything any why this happening i also tried to view page source but that section go blank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my views

```
class home(View):
    def get(self, request):
        quote = Quote.objects.all()
        return render(request, 'home.html', {'qoutes':quote}) # <--Here
```

You have a typo in your view, "qoutes".

you pass into your context dictionnary the "qoutes" key, so when you try to iterate on it in your template :

```
 {% for Quote in quotes %}
```

Your template can't find "quotes" because it only knows "qoutes".

Comment: what typo in my views

Comment: Updated my comment with more explanations :)

Comment: oh yes sorry my bad